# Swift: How to dynamically append value(s) into string of dictionary from an array of Int

Tags: swift, algorithm

Let say I have array of Int:

```
var intArr = [1,2,3,4]
```

and a string of dictionary:

```
var dictString = "[{\"id\": value1, {\"id\":value2,}, {\"id\":value3}, {\"id\":value4}]"
```

those value1,2,3,4 are Int type aswell

and I want to replace value1,2,3,4 with the value from stringArr. My expectation is something like

```
"[{\"id\": 1, {\"id\":2,}, {\"id\":3}, {\"id\":4}]"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Either replace `value1` to `intArr[0]` with `replaceOcurencesOf()` treating as a String, or convert your JSONString into an Array of objects, and iterate to replace the value...$

Comment: @JoakimDanielson hey I just updated my question, hopefully it is clear enough

Comment: Thank you @Larme, I love your solution with "replaceOcurencesOf()" but the value1,2,3,4 could be changed and they will not always be the same every time I fetch the Json.

Comment: Is your JSON String as such (because it's missing a `}` after `value1`? And why do you keep it as as String?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Isn't that an array of dictionary instead?

Comment: @Larme I totally misread the input string and made things much more complicated for myself because of that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this you can achieve by one of the fowling way

**Note:** I'm assuming that you have below input

```
var intArr = [1,2,3,4]
var dictString = "[{\"id\": 0}, {\"id\":0}, {\"id\":0}, {\"id\":0}]"
```

**Method 1:**
Write an extension for `String`

```
extension String {
    func getMapped(with list: [Int]) -> String? {
        guard let jsonData = self.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        do{
            var counter = -1
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as? [[String: Int]]{
                let result = json.map { ob -> [String: Int] in
                    counter += 1
                    return counter < list.count ? ["id" : list[counter]] : ob
                }
                return String(describing: result)
            }
        }catch let e {
            print("e \(e)")
            return nil
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now you can call that function

```
print(dictString.getMapped(with: intArr))
Output: Optional("[[\"id\": 1], [\"id\": 2], [\"id\": 3], [\"id\": 4]]")
```

**Method 2:**
Since I can see the `id` is in common for all dictionary objects, so you can simply map your `intArry` to convert to array of dictionary objects.

```
    let mapped = intArr.map({["id": $0]})
    let mappedString = String(describing: mapped)
    print(mappedString)
    Output: [["id": 1], ["id": 2], ["id": 3], ["id": 4]]
```

**Edit:** Editing my answer for method2 approach to address the @Larme's comment.

```
let mapped = intArr.map({["id": $0]})
let mappedString = String(describing: NSArray(array: mapped))
print(mappedString)
Output:
(
        {
        id = 1;
    },
        {
        id = 2;
    },
        {
        id = 3;
    },
        {
        id = 4;
    }
)
```

Comment: You aren't returning the same thing: You are using `[` & `]` instead of `{`&`}` to delimit dictionary (which isn't JSON compliant), and rely on `description` (which is usually a bad idea) to do so...

Comment: @Larme It doesn't matter `{` & `}` to represent the dictionary in swift. In Swift array and dictionary can be represented as `[]`  and `[:]`. In can if you still need to represent it as `{}` delimit dictionary you can do like this `let mappedString = String(describing: NSArray(array: mapped))`

Comment: But now, you are using `NSDictionary`/`NSArray` `description`. Indded, you have `{`/`}` for dictionaries, but have `(`/`)` for Arrays, "=" to separate key/values, and `;`. I don't know why you answer was marked as correct by OP, since (let's forget about the forgotten } typo), the expected output was JSON... Which isn't your case. And let me ask you this: From your output, can you modify the dict where id is 3 to 55? Is your output reusable in other words... I know that for the last one it is (because it has special condition on creation, but that's a trick known by few developers)...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution here is to ignore the `dictString` and instead created an array of dictionaries using the intArray and then encode it and convert the result to a string

```
var intArr = [1,2,3,4]

let output = intArr.reduce(into: []) { $0.append(["id": $1])}
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(output)
let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
```